# Console.log() in node works but not document.write() after browserify

Tags: javascript, browserify

I am running a small piece of code to understand how browserify works.  The code is using the json-rpc2 module.  I have a file `test.js`

```
var rpc = require('json-rpc2')
var client = rpc.Client.$create(8545, 'localhost');
client.call('eth_coinbase', [], function(err, result) {
    console.log(result);
}
```

If I run `node test.js` like normal the code runs fine and the output is correctly written to the terminal.  However, if I change `console.log(result)` to `document.write(result)`, browserify it to a file `bundle.js` and include it in an HTML file when I run the web page nothing is written to the screen.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I feel like this is a no-brainer, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Probably `document` is not defined. Try `console.log(document);` and check the result.

Comment: Isn't `document` defined when a web page is opened in Chromium?

Comment: It returned 'document is not defined' , how do I define document then?

Comment: If you are using jQuery you can try `$(document).ready()`, if you want a pure javascript solution check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-of-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-t)

Comment: There are instances (like in an addon) that a JS can run before DOM is created.

Comment: Why you need to use `document.write`? Seems to be a little bit strange.

Comment: @Frogmouth I'm just using it for testing purposes, if there's an easier way I'm all ears.

Comment: In general I avoid `document.write` because of its habit of clearing the document if called after the document has loaded (which *may* be happening to you).  It also has some weird edge cases with async scripts and iframes.

Comment: @jojeyh - when You told: "It returned 'document is not defined' , how do I define document then?" you see this debug information from Browser console or in terminal?

Comment: @Frogmouth I do not see anything in the browser console when I run `console.log(document)`.